# Using jQuery to style radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to style the following example so that the checked radio buttons are styled with different `background-color` when they are checked.

I've managed to put this together from other posts on SO as I don't know jQuery, as far as I can see there isn't a way to do this in pure CSS as the label is a parent of the input.

The HTML code cannot be changed as that is being output by an Shiny interface in R.

Currently the background will remain checked. I have tried styling both the checked and unchecked at once - but that did not seem to work.

```js
$('.radio-inline input').click(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]:checked').parent().css("background-color","#d10000").css("color","#FFF");
});
```

```css
.shiny-options-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}

.shiny-options-group label {
  float: left;
}

.shiny-options-group label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9%;
  background-color: #d2e9ef;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shiny-options-group input{
 display: none;
}

label input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_Q1">
  <div id="tb_Q">
    <div id="Q1_text" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tb_Qt">
    <div id="Q1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_ans">
    <div id="Q1_Ans" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container shiny-input-container-inline">
      <div class="shiny-options-group">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="1" checked="checked"/>
          <span>1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="2"/>
          <span>2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="3"/>
          <span>3</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="4"/>
          <span>4</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="5"/>
          <span>5</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="6"/>
          <span>6</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="7"/>
          <span>7</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="8"/>
          <span>8</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="9"/>
          <span>9</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="10"/>
          <span>10</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="11"/>
          <span>11</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="12"/>
          <span>12</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div_Q2">
  <div id="tb_Q">
    <div id="Q2_text" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tb_Qt">
    <div id="Q2" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_ans">
    <div id="Q2_Ans" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container shiny-input-container-inline">
      <div class="shiny-options-group">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="1" checked="checked"/>
          <span>1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="2"/>
          <span>2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="3"/>
          <span>3</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="4"/>
          <span>4</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="5"/>
          <span>5</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="6"/>
          <span>6</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="7"/>
          <span>7</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="8"/>
          <span>8</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="9"/>
          <span>9</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="10"/>
          <span>10</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="11"/>
          <span>11</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="12"/>
          <span>12</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `Q1_Ans` for both questions? They will be treated as one set of radio buttons.

Comment: @JLRishe, i didnt, i just had to copy paste a duplicate so i will fix that. But both of the responses work so far which is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the styles from the ones that aren't checked, or they will keep the styles that you've added.

And it's probably better if you use a CSS style rule to specify the styles.

```js
$('.radio-inline input').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.shiny-options-group')
         .find('.radio-inline')
         .removeClass('checked');
  $(this).parent()
         .addClass('checked');
 });
```

```css
.shiny-options-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}

.shiny-options-group label {
  float: left;
}

.shiny-options-group label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9%;
  background-color: #d2e9ef;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shiny-options-group input{
 display: none;
}

label input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span {
    color: #FFF;
}

.radio-inline.checked {
    background-color: #d10000;
}

.radio-inline.checked span {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_Q1">
  <div id="tb_Q">
    <div id="Q1_text" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tb_Qt">
    <div id="Q1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_ans">
    <div id="Q1_Ans" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container shiny-input-container-inline">
      <div class="shiny-options-group">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="1" checked="checked"/>
          <span>1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="2"/>
          <span>2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="3"/>
          <span>3</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="4"/>
          <span>4</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="5"/>
          <span>5</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="6"/>
          <span>6</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="7"/>
          <span>7</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="8"/>
          <span>8</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="9"/>
          <span>9</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="10"/>
          <span>10</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="11"/>
          <span>11</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="12"/>
          <span>12</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div_Q2">
  <div id="tb_Q">
    <div id="Q2_text" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tb_Qt">
    <div id="Q2" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_ans">
    <div id="Q2_Ans" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container shiny-input-container-inline">
      <div class="shiny-options-group">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="1" checked="checked"/>
          <span>1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="2"/>
          <span>2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="3"/>
          <span>3</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="4"/>
          <span>4</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="5"/>
          <span>5</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="6"/>
          <span>6</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="7"/>
          <span>7</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="8"/>
          <span>8</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="9"/>
          <span>9</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="10"/>
          <span>10</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="11"/>
          <span>11</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2_Ans" value="12"/>
          <span>12</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.siblings()` to toggle to `background-color` and `color` of sibling elements to current `<label>` element

```js
$('.radio-inline input').click(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]:checked').parent()
  .css({"background-color":"#d10000"
  , "color":"#FFF"})
  .siblings()
  .css({"background-color":"#d2e9ef"
  , "color":"#000"})
 });
```

```css
.shiny-options-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}

.shiny-options-group label {
  float: left;
}

.shiny-options-group label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9%;
  background-color: #d2e9ef;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shiny-options-group input{
 display: none;
}

label input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span {
    color: #FFF;
}

label:checked {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_Q1">
  <div id="tb_Q">
    <div id="Q1_text" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tb_Qt">
    <div id="Q1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_ans">
    <div id="Q1_Ans" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container shiny-input-container-inline">
      <div class="shiny-options-group">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="1" checked="checked"/>
          <span>1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="2"/>
          <span>2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="3"/>
          <span>3</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="4"/>
          <span>4</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="5"/>
          <span>5</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="6"/>
          <span>6</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="7"/>
          <span>7</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="8"/>
          <span>8</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="9"/>
          <span>9</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="10"/>
          <span>10</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="11"/>
          <span>11</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="12"/>
          <span>12</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div_Q2">
  <div id="tb_Q">
    <div id="Q2_text" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tb_Qt">
    <div id="Q2" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_ans">
    <div id="Q1_Ans" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container shiny-input-container-inline">
      <div class="shiny-options-group">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="1" checked="checked"/>
          <span>1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="2"/>
          <span>2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="3"/>
          <span>3</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="4"/>
          <span>4</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="5"/>
          <span>5</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="6"/>
          <span>6</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="7"/>
          <span>7</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="8"/>
          <span>8</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="9"/>
          <span>9</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="10"/>
          <span>10</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="11"/>
          <span>11</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Q1_Ans" value="12"/>
          <span>12</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

1.I do not know if it is the best example of optimization, but it is a solution, I hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("document loaded");
  var id1 = true; var id2 = true; var id3 = true; var id4 = true;
  $("#myId1").on('click', function(){
   $("#myId1").removeClass('myClass').addClass('myNewClass');
   id1 = false;
   if(id2 === false || id3 == false || id4 == false){
    $("#myId2").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    $("#myId3").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    $("#myId4").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    id2 = true; id3 = true; id4 = true;
   }
  });
  $("#myId2").on('click', function(){
   $("#myId2").removeClass('myClass').addClass('myNewClass');
   id2 = false;
   if(id1 == false || id3 == false || id4 == false){
    $("#myId1").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    $("#myId3").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    $("#myId4").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    id1 = true; id3 = true; id4 = true;
   }
  });
  $("#myId3").on('click', function(){
   $("#myId3").removeClass('myClass').addClass('myNewClass');
   id3 = false;
   if(id1 == false || id2 == false || id4 == false){
    $("#myId1").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    $("#myId2").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    $("#myId4").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    id1 = true; id2 = true; id4 = true;
   }
  });
  $("#myId4").on('click', function(){
   $("#myId4").removeClass('myClass').addClass('myNewClass');
   id4 = false;
   if(id1 == false || id2 == false || id3 == false){
    $("#myId1").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    $("#myId2").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    $("#myId3").removeClass('myNewClass').addClass('myClass');
    id1 = true; id2 = true; id3 = true;
   }
  });

 });
</script>
<style>
 .myClass {
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 }
 .myNewClass {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myId1" class="myClass"><p style="padding-top: 5px;">1</p></div>
<div id="myId2" class="myClass"><p style="padding-top: 5px;">2</p></div>
<div id="myId3" class="myClass"><p style="padding-top: 5px;">3</p></div>
<div id="myId4" class="myClass"><p style="padding-top: 5px;">4</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP said that they can't change the HTML structure, and what does this giant mass of redundant code accomplish?

Comment: I don't think id ever use this over an existing response, its about 10x longer.